# Setting up tailwindCSS with the storybook, reactjs and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, storybook

I've been trying for so long to make tailwindCSS to work along with ReactJS, storybook and typescript but no luck so far. Here is some of my configs to make it work as per the documentation along with some tutorials:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
},
"include": ["src"]
```

}

**tailwind.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
purge: [],
darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
theme: {
    extend: {},
},
variants: {
    extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
```

**postcss.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
},
```

**main.ts**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
   stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
   addons: [
      "@storybook/addon-links",
      "@storybook/addon-essentials",
      "@storybook/addon-interactions",
      "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
   ],
   framework: "@storybook/react",
   core: {
     builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
   },
   webpackFinal: async (config) => {
   config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\,css&/,
        use: [
                {
                   loader: "postcss-loader",
                   options: {
                        ident: "postcss",
                        plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
                   },
                 },
              ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
        });
        return config;
      },
    };
```

**preview.ts**

```
import "index.css";

export const parameters = {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
       matchers: {
          color: /(background|color)$/i,
          date: /Date$/,
       },
     },
 };
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind forms;
```

I've tried to add tailwindCSS classes to some components but it looks like something is wrong. Would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Import tailwindcss in your preview.js file like this:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

[Reference](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/6314#issuecomment-1018747989)